# After requesting Paid Application Contract and having it in the effect, Builds not visible on iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, app-store-connect, xcode9.1

My application is Free and there is no In-App Purchase in it. 
This is a Xamarin.Forms application and I have installed XCode 9.1 in my mac.

I tried to create new version on iTunesConnect & it pops up a message as below, may be because my client requested the Paid Application Contract:

[image: Paid Application Schedule]

Now I have two contracts in place, Paid and Free as below:

[image: Contracts in effect]

Now, I could able to create a new version under iTunesConnect.

I uploaded the new version of the app using "Application Loader" and first time I got warning message about missing app icon for the iOS 11.

I corrected it and uploaded same version with the new build number again and "Application Loader" gave me Success.

I waited for whole day and when Build didn't appear, I tried to upload again with new build number and I am still waiting for the last 2 weeks for my build to appear under Build section. Still no luck!!

[image: Build]

Also, it shows me below message as well(However, my app has no such in-app purchase feature):

[image: InAppPurchaseAlert]

Will someone please help me to rectify the issue?

Comment: If you don't have an In-App Purchases product， there's no need to configure the feature tab. Try to upload your project with the same version and build you uploaded before. Verify whether it will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your response!. I gave it a try too. Yes, it is failing saying that this build already there in itunesconnect. This means my iPA is added to the apple server but it is not being displayed under Builds section.

Comment: Please check the Apple ID which you login the Application Loader. Then contact with the support of Apple.

Comment: @MilanG the notice explicitly says that someone needs to Review the licence before updating any applications (it doesn't exclude the free ones directly ) so have you reviewed and accepted it. I'm assuming that if you don't accept it no updates aren't going through.

Comment: @OlliTyynelä : Yes, it is accepted and now that alert is not displayed anymore. Now the problem is last two screenshots in my question. Build is not displayed and my app has no in-app purchase feature. Is it due to the "Paid Application" contract, my free app builds are not visible?

Comment: I'd contact apple my self and ask, but personally I wouldn't try to put an app as an "paid application" if it didn't have any in app purchases. Personally I'm not sure will they review the app if you don't set anything on the app purchases section as the app doesn't have any.

Comment: So, does it mean that, Paid Application contract is only for the In-App purchase and if my app has no this feature, I should ask Apple to remove the Paid Application contract, keeping only the free one? Is my understanding correct?